# Recursive function

Tags: haskell, recursion

I am having trouble with an exercise where I should define a function which takes as input an integer, a character and a string and returns the result of putting the character in the string at the position specified by the integer, for example, giving `3`, `'a'` and `"haskell"` to the function should result in `"hasakell"`.

```
putinto :: Int -> Char -> String -> String
putinto
```

Comment: Show us, what did you try ?

Comment: Which coding/programming language are you asking about?

Answer (score 6):

Think about it this way: having a list where the first element is called 'x' and the rest of the list is called 'xs' (in Haskell, this would be written as `(x:xs)`), you either prepend your given value to the list of the position is 0. Otherwise you call yourself recursively on the remained of the list (and decrease the poisition).

```
putinto :: Int -> a -> [a] -> [a]
putinto 0 value list   = value : list
putinto n value (x:xs) = x : putinto (n-1) value xs
```

In case it looks odd, the `(x:xs)` is actually a "deconstructed" list. The `x` represents the first element of the list, `xs` (the 's' means 'plural', so it's the plural of 'x') is the rest of the list.

So calling it with a zero will actually prepend the given value, as in

```
putinto 0 'a' "haskell"  -- yields 'ahaskell'
```

Calling it with two will be:

```
putinto 2 'a' "haskell"
-- same as 'h' : putinto 1 'a' "askell"
-- same as 'h' : 'a' : putinto 0 'a' "skell"
-- same as 'h' : 'a' : 'a' : "skell"
-- same as "haaskell"
```

You still need to care about error checking (what if the given position is negative, or larger than the list length?) though.

Comment: re: Error Checking.  In Haskell, this cannot just be "added in" the type signature of the function has to change to something like `Int -> a -> [a] -> Maybe [a].  Since this is not in the type signature for the problem, I would suggest the best thing to do is just fail quickly.

Answer (score 3):

```
int j = 3;
char a = 'a';
string x = "haskell";

string part1 = x.Substring(0, j);
string part2 = x.Substring(j);
string result = part1 + a + part2;
```

this wil do the trick in C#

Comment: sorry didn't understand that it had to haskell, haven't heard about it i am sorry

Comment: +1: Answered at a time, where Haskell was not specifically marked as a requirement.

Comment: excerpt from the original question: `putinto:: Int -> Char -> String -> String`. does this look C# to you?

Answer (score 3):

Before writing an explicitly recursive solution to a problem involving lists in Haskell, it's worth checking to see if the same task can be accomplished using the list functions in the `Prelude` or `Data.List`. In this case `splitAt` can help:

```
splitAt 3 "haskell"
("has","kell")
```

Thus your problem is easily solved by splitting, consing and appending:

```
putInto :: Int -> Char -> String -> String
putInto n c xs = let (ys,zs) = splitAt n xs in ys ++ (c:zs)
```

Just for fun, the above can also be written in a point-free style using the applicative instance for `(-> r)`:

```
putInto :: Int -> Char -> String -> String
putInto n c = ((++) . fst <*> (c:) . snd) . splitAt n
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be fairly easy to read. I enumerated the lines for explanation:

```
1. putInto :: Int -> Char -> String -> String
2. putInto 0 a xs     = a:xs
3. putInto _ a []     = [a]
4. putInto n a (x:xs) = x : putInto (n-1) a xs
```

What goes on here? The first line is the type signature. The second line checks if you wish to set the character at the front (ie. index 0).

The third and fourth line is for when we wish to insert it later than the 0'th index. The third line checks if the list we want to insert into is empty, in which case we just return the list containing only `a`.

In the fourth line we know that the first index of our string will still be the first, so we just recurse on the tail, decreasing `n` as needed along the way.

Comment: Note that this will throw an error when the index is greater than the length of the string.

Comment: Fixed that by adding a clause. It will still enter an infinite loop if n is negative though.

Comment: If `n` is negative, `a` will be added at the end of the list.